# Как отвязать действие (Action) в Blender от скелета, чтобы удалить его?

Tags: blender

Столкнулся с проблемой в Blender. Удаляю все ключи в Action, удаляю саму Action, а она не удаляется. "0" за ней не появляется. Если я к примеру создам новое Action, а затем удалю его, то за его названием появляется "0" и при следующем открытии модели, пустого Action с "0" в названии уже нет. Но мне нужно удалить Actions в которых уже были ключи. Но видимо удаления самих ключей для этого не достаточно. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы они исчезли из списка в редакторе действий?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно открыть окно редактора NLA, и все привязанные действия удалить в нем.

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите на крестик рядом с названием дата-блока с зажатым <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Comment: Ваш способ не помог, но я уже сам решил свою проблему, спасибо.